# <cfajaxproxy> Locked-Down production Lucee

Tags: coldfusion, firewall, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10, lucee

Setting up production lucee box, having issues locating ajax library in lucee server. My browser unable to find ajax library showing 404 error.

I am not sure this is because of firewall or lucee server configuration issue.

My development and staging working fine only having issue in production server.

```
Request URL: https://example.com/mapping-tag/lucee/core/ajax/JSLoader.cfc?method=get&lib=LuceeAjax
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 
Remote Address: 201.10.26.29:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Please advise..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an Adobe CF server, the JS files related to `cfajaxproxy` are in the `/CFIDE/scripts/` folder. The `/CFIDE/` folder is removed from public access when the server is locked down. To allow access to the JS files for the UI and ajax tags, you can specify an alias in CF Admin for that folder.

For example, `/cfjs` would map to `/CFIDE/scripts` in CF Amin, so CF will generate that path for `cfajaxproxy` use. You'd have to create this folder alias in IIS or whatever web server you're using.

If on Lucee, the folder `/lucee/core/` is blocked when locked down, there should be a similar solution for that engine.

Comment: Thank you  my netops team blocked lucee server access somehow they blocked everything from firewall now they allowed lucee library things under control.